# Qt QSwipeView with dynamic "interactive" breaks "currentIndex" binding

Tags: qt, qml

I'm trying to create a **SwipeView** where the first page has the `interactive` property false, while the others have it enabled. The effect that I'm trying to achieve is to have the main page with a link to the others, but the others can only go back to the main page (like the iOS settings menu).

The issue is that after the first change page, the `currentIndex` property loses binding causing the **SwipeView** to break.

Here's the application output:

```
qrc:/main.qml:10:5: QML SwipeView: Binding loop detected for property "currentIndex"
file:///home/rcc/Qt/5.12.6/gcc_64/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/SwipeView.qml:49:18: QML ListView: Binding loop detected for property "currentIndex"
```

and here's the default swipe view application (QtCreator -> New Project -> Qt Quick Application - Swipe) `main.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Tabs")

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        interactive: false

        onCurrentIndexChanged: {
            if (currentIndex === 0) {
                interactive = false
            } else {
                interactive = true
            }
        }

        Page1Form {}

        Page2Form {}
    }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex

        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 1")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Page 2")
        }
    }
}
```

To reproduce the bug:

- Click on **Page 2**.
- Swipe left.
- Click again on **Page 2**.

Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: At first glance it looks like a bug. Please report it at bugreports.qt.io.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm [still looking into this](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-80750), but for now you should be able to work around it by delaying the assignment to the interactive property:

```
onCurrentIndexChanged: {
    if (currentIndex === 0) {
        Qt.callLater(function() { interactive = false })
    } else {
        Qt.callLater(function() { interactive = true })
    }
}
```